# Openlayers 3 - how do I preload a static image not in current view

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

I'm creating a map that contains 2 static images, one positioned above the other. On the initial load, the view is set to show the upper image only. When panning down, there is a slight delay whilst the lower image loads.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pL7pgL3g/2/) shows the problem - when panning down there is a short delay then the image is loaded. If you change the center from `center: [500,500],` to `center: [500,0],` then both images are loaded at the same time.

Is it possible to load an image that is not in view so when I pan to it there is no delay at all?

Comment: Maybe you try something using browser cache.

Comment: The images I will be loading will change every few days so caching them in the browser may create more issues than it solves.